# Spark nested RDD limitation

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

It looks like not able to perform nested RDD operations is a limitation of Spark am facing now.

Currently, I have two datasets (say A and B) loaded from different tables, for 
each record in the Dataset A, I need to query against the other dataset B. And the result is further transformed before committing it to the database.

Join won't work in this case either as suggested in some other SO questions I've seen.
for example, the nested spark Sql query is something like this:

```
foreach(r => ...
   select x,y,z from A
   where k in (select i from B where j=r)
```

So how do I process each record of A against B with nesting.

Thanks

Comment: You need to explain it a bit more.

Comment: I think a join will work actually, but you really will need to describe what you are trying to do more clearly.